# connecting with JBOSS EAP to H2 Console (Red Hat - Ticketmonster tutorial )

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, redhat, jboss-eap-6

I'm doing the Red Hat TicketMonster tutorial but got stuck pretty fast. 
You can find the tutorial (pdf) [here](http://developers.redhat.com/ticket-monster/)

The problem: 
At first everything worked just fine. I managed to deploy the app on localhost, could see the tables using h2console etc.

But when I decided to continue later, I couldn't enter the console like I did before. So I installed the H2 database engine and am able to at least log in but now my tables are gone.

I didn't change anything in the -ds.xml file (just added some Entities in the model package) and use the same url in the database engine.

Maybe the database is locked?

```
<connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
```

I don't know what went wrong and what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, found the reason why the connection to h2 console didn't work.

Apparently I didn't deploy the h2console.war in the right folder after changing the runtime server (to Wildfly).